# How to mock a static Sitecore method?

Tags: sitecore, moq, xunit, autofixture

we have a static Sitecore method which is called when we fire the test we need to mock the method result, means when its called it should return our mocked result and shouldn't enter into that method.

public class UnitTest1
{

```
[Theory, DefaultAutoData]
public void CreateDatabase(Database database)
{
    Assert.NotNull(database);
}

[Theory, DefaultAutoData]
public void GetItem(Database db, Item item)
{
    item["Phrase"].Returns("Welcome!");
    db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Error Codes/500 Error").Returns(item);
    var i = new ItemRepository();  //error here
    Assert.Equal("Welcome!", item["Phrase"]);
    Assert.NotNull(i);
}
```

}

Because in item repository the SitecoreContext.Dictionary() method is Static and somehow calling a method which has a parameter of SitecoreContext which gets null.
How do we mock this method so if it fires it shouldn't go inside the static method its should return what we've defined?

Comment: Is this a Sitecore `ItemRepository` or a custom one? What exactly this test is supposed to check?

Comment: This is a custom class where it has 1 global variable which is assigned to that Sitecore Static Method.

Comment: You're asking about some error in a class which is not provided... How to answer that? Please share a [minimal reproducible scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't have Access to that piece of code but if you can guide how to mock a static method like when its called it shouldn't go into the method directly returns the expected output.

`mockService.Setup(service => service.GetValue()).Returns(expectedValue);`

This works with the normal method but doesn't work with the static method

Comment: If you don't have access to those code, why do you call it in tests? Abstract it away. You don't want to unit test someone's internal implementation in your code. You should test _your_ scenarios.

Comment: I've haven't added that code in test its a part of the original code, how can I abstract that  method which I want to skip?

Comment: In the test you're just creating an instance of `ItemRepository` and never use it. So, either: 1) it's redundant and must be removed or 2) the test is incomplete, please provide a proper test case in the question. Anyway, if you do not own the `ItemRepository` class, you'd better not call it in unit test because of the exact this reason. _Something_ fails inside and you do not controll it. Dont call it. Abstract.